# batch script text file input to organize folders

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am new to scripting.

I would like to create a batch file that looks through a specific source folder and matches the first 8 character of the file to the 8 character in a text file and move it across to specific folder.

For example:

I have a file in `C:\ ABCDEFGHblahblah.pdf`

A text file stored in batch file directory called BPD, contains numerous comma delimited 8 characters like ABCDEFGH, STUVWXYZ.

Script has to search for the content of the all the txt files (in the batch file directory)then if  ABCDEFGH exist in BPD.txt file then move ABCDEFGHblahblah.pdf to BPD folder, if the folder doesn’t exist create it.

Reason why I am looking for a text file as an external source is because 8 characters are extremely  dynamic and power user can add/delete/edit  new characters as they see fit.

I am thinking ..

```
 @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET sourcedir="C:\Test"
    SET batchtxt="C:\BPD.txt, KLM.txt"
    SET destdir="C:\Test"
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
      'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
     ) DO (
      MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\!name!\" >nul
    )
```

This doesn’t work, please help

Comment: Tell us what happens and why you don't think it works.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] to understand the rules and requirements for asking good questions on SO.

Comment: Post a few lines in your question from the text file containing the filename/directory pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
SET "textfiles=c:\bpd\*.txt"
:: For my testing
SET "textfiles=q20649661.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=, " %%a IN ("%textfiles%") do (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a*.pdf" (
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%b"
  ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a*.pdf" "%destdir%\%%b\"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

'fraid your specification is as clear as mud.

For my testing, I set up `q20649661.txt` with content

```
ABCDEFGH, STUVWXYZ
```

and established a file called `c:\sourcedir\ABCDEFGH123.pdf`

The result of the run was

```
MD "c:\destdir\STUVWXYZ"
MOVE "c:\sourcedir\ABCDEFGH*.pdf" "c:\destdir\STUVWXYZ\"
```

which I think is what you may want.

Note that appending `2>nul` to the `MD` command will suppress ugly error message when the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not bulletproof but can be used as base and adapted as needed.

Real file/folder operations are preceded by a `ECHO` command. If output to console is correct, remove `ECHO` move files / create folders.

```
@echo off

    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure source of files
    set "sourceDir=c:\test"
    set "targetDir=c:\test\output"

    rem Read all data in ???.txt files in batch file directory into environment variables
    for %%f in ("%~dp0\???.txt") do for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%l in ("%%~ff") do for %%t in (%%l) do set "_$%%~t=%%~nf"

    rem For each file in source directory
    for %%f in ("%sourceDir%\*") do (

        rem take 8 characters from file name and retrieve target from environment variable
        set "target=%%~nf"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%i in ("!target:~0,8!") do set "target=!_$%%~i!"

        rem if target found, move the file to target directory
        if defined target (
            if not exist "%targetDir%\!target!" ECHO md "%targetDir%\!target!" >nul 
            ECHO move "%%~ff" "%targetDir%\!target!"
        )
        endlocal
    )

    rem Clean
    endlocal
```